# Identify disks on an LSI SAS1068E controller

Tags: linux, storage, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, raid1

I'm trying to identify clearly which disk needs replacing in a RAID1 array. The controller shows it's PhysDisk 0 id=1. When opening up the machine how do I know for sure which disk this is? 
(Ideally by serial number on disk and not just physical cable connected to..)

Is there a way to show the serial numbers of disks through the lsiutil command line utility or otherwise?

Centos 5.4

Dell Poweredge R300

Dell (pretend) RAID SAS6iR controller (aka LSI SAS0168E)

2x WD 160Gb disks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question - had totally forgotten about OpenManage (OMSA). Installing this beast and several megs of rpms later:

```
[root@computeu1n5 ~]# omreport storage pdisk controller=0
List of Physical Disks on Controller SAS 6/iR Adapter (Slot 1)

Controller SAS 6/iR Adapter (Slot 1)
...
ID                        : 0:1
Status                    : Ok
Name                      : Physical Disk 0:1
...
Serial No.                : WD-WCAS2208118581185
...
```

BINGO!

Comment: Alternatively - credit to Tim on linux-poweredge list: lscsi -g and sg_inq do the trick (in packages lsscsi sg3_utils). Without requiring megabytes of omsa overkill!

Answer (score 1):

This command will show serial numbers of discs attached to a LSI SAS controller:

`yum install lsscsi 
/usr/bin/lsscsi -g
smartctl -a /dev/sg0`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to blink the disk activity lights within the RAID utility.

Comment: I can't see that option and as the drives are internal and not hot-swappable from what I remember so there aren't external status lights as on say the PERC controllers. It really is a crap controller!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the LSIUtil software uses similar syntax to the MegaCli utility that Dell oem's from LSILogic,   I would start with the [Perc Cheat Sheet written by Moritz Mertinkat:](http://tools.rapidsoft.de/perc/perc-cheat-sheet.html)

```
# Physical drive information

MegaCli -PDList -aALL
MegaCli -PDInfo -PhysDrv [E:S] -aALL
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to. The 1068E is barely more than a software RAID controller *sobs*.